# How to call TextChanged event of parent page, using javascript from Child Page?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I set value of textbox on a parent page using javascript on child pop up window, but this does not trigger the textchanged event of the parent textbox. I believe it requires postback in order to fire textchanged event. So I did this..

**CHILD POPUP**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function updateParent(val, controlname) {
            window.opener.document.getElementById(controlname).value = val;
            __doPostBack(document.getElementById(controlname), '');//Added this line
        }

    </script>
```

But it is still not working. Even if it does I am afraid it will reopen the pop once again since it will cause postback. Any ideas? Try to keep it simple.

Comment: When do you want to fire the textchanged event? Is it after the child windows closes or as soon as the value is entered and confirmed in child window?

Comment: @SystemOnline I have a GridView on ChildPopUp with linkButtons in it, as soon as user clicks on any of it.. the Child Window closes and the textbox value on the parent is set. So yes I would like to fire this textbox changed even as soon as the child window closes.

Comment: I am not pretty sure, but you can do following - set the value in a hidden field on parent page, instead of directly in the textbox. When child window closed and focus goes back to parent, check the value of hidden field and set it to textbox and empty the hidden field value. This will fire the textchanged event of the textbox.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Javascript on parent window.

```
<script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript"> 
  function domycallback(controlname,val) 
   { 
        document.getElementById(controlname).value = val;
        __doPostBack(document.getElementById(controlname), '');
        return false; 
   } 
</script>
```

Javascript on Child window.

```
window.opener.domycallback();
```

Comment: What is this supposed to do? Set text of parent page TextBox? I am already able to change the textbox value of parent page but I am not able to fire its textchanged event.

Comment: I did. Nothing happens. I am getting this on Child PopUp's console.. `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null`

Comment: @Arbaaz jsfiddle link pls

Comment: I cant give you jsfiddle link sorry.. I have GridViews on both parent and child page.